# How to replace word from sentence with selected word?

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace

```
DECLARE @WHERE VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @WHERE='FROM USER T0 WHERE 1=1 AND (T0.SUBDIVISION = N''RESID'' OR T0.SUBDIVISION = N''PARK HYATT BC'' OR T0.SUBDIVISION = N''RESID,PARK HYATT BC'' ) AND (T0.IDCPROPERTYTYPE = N''RESIDENTIAL'' ) AND (T0.IDCSTATUS = N''ACTIVE'' OR T0.IDCSTATUS = N''UNDER CONTRACT'' ) AND T0.IDCLATITUDE BETWEEN 39@604095464559996 AND 39,606546508 AND T0.IDCLONGITUDE BETWEEN -1066,5164566858 AND -106.51645654'
SET @WHERE =REPLACE(@WHERE, ',', '@');

SELECT @WHERE
```

**This is the result of the above query.But if there is any "," in statement it also replaced.Is there any other option?**

```
"FROM DFT_CMNCMN t0 WHERE 1=1 AND (t0.SUBDIVISION = N'Resid' OR t0.SUBDIVISION = N'Park Hyatt BC' OR t0.SUBDIVISION = N'Resid@Park Hyatt BC' ) AND (t0.IDCPROPERTYTYPE = N'residential' ) AND (t0.IDCSTATUS = N'active' OR t0.IDCSTATUS = N'under contract' ) AND t0.IDCLATITUDE BETWEEN 39@6040654696999999996 AND 39@60654508 AND t0.IDCLONGITUDE BETWEEN -165406@516858 AND -105466.5154"
```

I need answer like below-

```
"FROM DFT_CMNCMN t0 WHERE 1=1 AND (t0.SUBDIVISION = N'Resid' OR t0.SUBDIVISION = N'Park Hyatt BC' OR t0.SUBDIVISION = N'**Resid@Park Hyatt BC**' ) AND (t0.IDCPROPERTYTYPE = N'residential' ) AND (t0.IDCSTATUS = N'active' OR t0.IDCSTATUS = N'under contract' ) AND t0.IDCLATITUDE BETWEEN 39.604096546999999996 AND 39.66540508 AND t0.IDCLONGITUDE BETWEEN -10546.516858 AND -106654.56456154"
```

Comment: What is the difference between your output and expected one except some missing numbers?

Comment: i just only want replace this Resid,Park Hyatt BC word to Resid@Park Hyatt BC

Comment: You can simply use REPLACE(your_string,'Resid,Park Hyatt BC','Resid@Park Hyatt BC')

Comment: `SELECT REPLACE(STUFF(@WHERE, CHARINDEX(',', @WHERE)-1, 1, '@'), ',', '.')`?